# Set password for username with disabled-login

Tags: linux, user-accounts

I have install gitlab and as the installation manual says I needed to create a user with disabled login - 
 https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/5-0-stable/doc/install/installation.md#3-system-users

I want to install some ruby gems and I need to enter password for "git" user.. I am trying to press enter (for empty password) and the authentication fails.

How I can set password for this user? I have tried passwd but it keeps asking me for the current password which I dont know..

Answer (score 1):

You have to change/set the password as root: `passwd user` will change it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't sign in with that user, you sign in with your normal user and use sudo and su to assume that user's identity:

```
$ sudo su - git
```

Comment: The user is probably `git` according to [this doc](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/5-0-stable/doc/install/installation.md#4-gitlab-shell)